# A better admin interface for large Drupal menus

Tags: drupal, drupal-navigation

I'm building a large Drupal site with deep menus.  I'd like to give my client a better interface for finding the menu parent item.  With hundreds of items in the parent selector, it soon becomes really hard to find what you need.

I've broken up my menus into "Primary Links" and 6 different product category menus.  That helps when you're in admin/build/menu... you can narrow down your choices.

But when creating/editing a page, I'd love to find a way to make the choices simpler.  Is there a module available to place the menus into separate parent item selectors?

Comment: To clarify, I think you are talking only about the dropdown in the node edit form, _not_ about the menu editing itself.

Comment: Yes, the dropdown in the node edit form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Menu Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_select) beta module was just released. It replaces the default menu parent item select on node edit forms with an expandable hierarchy and autoselect field. It also displays a preview breadcrumb above the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Menu Per Role module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role).  I hope this helps you

And I just Finished [Menu Auto Complete module](http://bazo0ka.com/menu_ac.zip)  . which will change your menu interface to auto complete .

Some Instructions :- if you have menu as the following

```
parent1 
 sub1
    subsub1
    subsub2
    subsub3
 sub2
 sub3
parent2
parent3 
parent4
```

you should know that the parents or the first elements like (parent1, parent2, parent3..)
are always prefixed  with "-- ".

so if you are going to search for "parent2" you should search for 
"-- par" 
and the menu auto complete will suggest all the parent elements that begin with "par"....if you are searching for "sub1" you should prefix it with "---- " .. if you are searching for "subsub1" you should prefix it with "------ "...and so on

sorry for my bad english && format...hop that will help u

Comment: I already use Menu Admin per Menu, and it appears this module is very similar.  So I've already limited access to the appropriate menus by role.  But I'd still like to get the one really long "parent item" select broken up into several smaller selects.

Comment: mmmm... so what about making menu select field is an auto complete field (together)...if  you like this lets go to the next step ..

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that.  The only problem is that it would still be nice to show the hierarchy of the menu(s), in case you have duplicate menu item names.

Answer (score 0):

Two modules you might find helpful:
[Menuless Node Type](http://drupal.org/project/menuless_nodetype)
[Menu settings per content type](http://drupal.org/project/ctm)

I generally prefer the first one, which just removes the menu dropdown.
The second one allows to enable only specific menus to choose from per node type.

---

You might also consider to create separate menus per language, although this does not directly help your cause, unless you want to do some custom module writing.

An interesting future module would be to provide a different form element for this, either an autocomplete textfield, or a popup based on ajax. Anything to reduce the html load on the node edit page.